# Defining void function in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I know that we can write functions in verilog just to display sth. like in the example below:

```
function ex_func;
    input op;
    input [1:0] in1;
    input [1:0] in2;
    input [1:0] out1;
    begin
        if(op)
            $display("%d <-- %d, %d", out1, in1, in2);
        else 
            $display("%d --> %d, %d", out1, in1, in2);
            
        ex_func = 0;
    end
endfunction
```

However I couldn't write this as void(not returning a value), so cannot use without equating to a temporary variable which is unnecessary. I can use in an ugly way:

```sh
// ...

reg temp; // temporary variable required for the function to work

initial begin
// ...

temp = ex_func(op[0], in1[0], in2[0], out1[0]);
#10;

// ...

temp = ex_func(op[1], in1[1], in2[1], out1[1]);
#10;

// ...
end
```

This works flawlessly, but as I said I want to write a function that does not return a value (void) and get rid of these ugly things. It seems that SystemVerilog supports void definition: https://verificationguide.com/systemverilog/systemverilog-functions/#Void_function , but same syntax does not work for Verilog ("Error:'void' is an unknown type") and I cannot find any other way or documentation about in Verilog.

So, the question is: Is there a way to define void function in Verilog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would use a task rather than a function as you are using it to display information only.

```
task ex_task;
    input op;
    input [1:0] in1;
    input [1:0] in2;
    input [1:0] out1;
    begin
        if(op)
            $display("%d <-- %d, %d", out1, in1, in2);
        else 
            $display("%d --> %d, %d", out1, in1, in2);
    end
endtask
```

Then you would call the task as you were hoping:

```
ex_task(op[0], in1[0], in2[0], out1[0]);
```

You can even add the delay in the task itself, which is another difference between functions and tasks.

```
task ex_task;
    input op;
    input [1:0] in1;
    input [1:0] in2;
    input [1:0] out1;
    begin
        if(op)
            $display("%d <-- %d, %d", out1, in1, in2);
        else 
            $display("%d --> %d, %d", out1, in1, in2);
        #10;
    end
endtask
```

Comment: It is weird that there are different syntaxes -not just `function`- to do very similar things. Anyway, I found a well-explained writing about differences between `function` and `task`: https://www.asic-world.com/verilog/task_func1.html

Comment: @Celuk I agree it is odd to have two different keywords and structures for similar operations. I believe the main driving force for the language definition differences is to keep time/tick based events separate (tasks) from procedural events (functions).